# Spring kafka consumer doesn't respect auto-offset-reset = latest

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have 1 Kafka Topic and 1 partition:

Seeing a rather strange behavior from the spring boot kafka consumer. Spring kafka consumer always consumes from the start of the topic on restart.
 I have configured the spring kafka listener as follows

kafka listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${application.kafkaInputTopic}", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
public void listen(String message) {
    log.debug("SG message received. Parsing...");
    TransmissionMessage transmissionMessage;
    SGTransmission transmission = parseMessage(message);
    //Porcess Transmission......
}
```

Consumer config and spring consumer container autowire beans

```
@Resource
public Environment env;

@Bean
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
   // I know this isnt right, should be run in 1 thread as there isonly 
   //partition in the topic
    factory.setConcurrency(10);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);

    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);

    factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap();
    propsMap.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, env.getProperty(Constants.SPRING_KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL));
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty(Constants.SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS));
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, env.getProperty(Constants.SPRING_KAFKA_GROUP_ID));
    return propsMap;
}
```

spring application yaml

```
kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
    properties:
    consumer:
        # If this consumer does not have an offset yet, start at latest offset.
        # Be careful with `earliest`, this will use the first (available) offset in the topic, which is most likely not what you want.
        auto-offset-reset: latest
        group-id: ${KAFKA_GROUP_ID}
```

Every time the consumer crashes and restarts all the messages are read from the start. which shouldnt be the case as you can see in the application.yaml

> auto-offset-reset: latest

Could there be some other config on broker side or consumer side that I may have ignored, which is causing the consumer to read from the start every time it restarts??

Comment: can you show the logs that shows which properties are loaded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have committed the initial offset somehow, perhaps before you finalized this configuration.

> factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);

That means you are responsible for committing the offsets.

Use `AckMode.BATCH` (the default) or `AckMode.RECORD`.

Or, delete the currently committed offset(s) with the `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI tool (you can use the same tool to list the current offsets too).

Or use a UUID for the group to get a new group each time.

**EDIT**

You can also have your listener class implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and call `callback.seekToEnd(partitions)` in `onPartitionsAssigned()`.

Comment: whats weird is that....we have the same consumer on another environment(another kafka topic and consumer group id but same java code)..and there the consumer is just fine after restart.

Comment: Right - it implies that this consumer has been run at least once with `earliest`. It's best to use a unique `group.id` if you always want to start at the latest.

Comment: so the initial offset is ´4226´ for the consumer group, in application logs it shows [Consumer clientId=consumer-10, groupId=group-id] Offset commit failed on partition my-topic-dev-0 at offset 4226: The coordinator is not aware of this member.

Comment: As I have 10 threads for my kafka container, I assume there are 10 different consumers belonging to the same group? but as there partition is only 1, nine consumers are supposed to be idle? please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: You are correct; it's pointless having more concurrency than partitions.

Comment: During rebalance of one of the kafka consumers(restart) assigned to the same topic it somehow managed to commit offset for the consumer group that doesn't exist on the  kafka topic since an year :-o   but this was on another environment which lead to kafka consumer rebalance failure I assume and the consumer then picked up from latest of the topic? I hope I am right this time as well ;)

Comment: Yes, whenever an offset is committed, the `auto.offset.reset` is ignored.